# Load images with jquery then run rest of scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small bit of code that gets my images from smugmug. My problem is that I need that to finish before the rest of my code imports and fires. I have looked at other posts, but none seemed to fit my particular situation.
the code looks like:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.slideShow = function(options) {
var albumID = options.albumID;
var size = options.size || "Medium";
var delay = options.delay || 3000;
var div = this;

// Setup div
this.empty();
div.append("<ul></ul>");
$("ul:first").attr("title","fashion");
$("ul:first").addClass("stretch");
ul = div.find("ul");

$.smugmug.login.anonymously(function() {
    $.smugmug.images.get({AlbumID: albumID, Heavy: 1}, function(images) {
        $.each(images.Images, function() {
            var url = this[size + "URL"];

            console.log("Add img" + url);
            ul.append("<li title=\"" +  url + "\" /></li>");
        });

    });
});

};


})(jQuery);
```

I am calling it out of the HTMLand passing params with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
nick = "hurleyhome";
    $(function() {
        $("#bg-images").slideShow({
            size: "Medium",
            albumID: "22516379",
            delay: 5000
        });
    });
</script>
```

The scripts I need to run after this one does are, standard JS imports from a script tag.

Any help would be apreciated.

I was considering a $(window).load event, but not exactly sure how to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get the question, but it looks like you already have a success function, just get the script there, like so:

```
$.smugmug.login.anonymously(function() {
    $.smugmug.images.get({AlbumID: albumID, Heavy: 1}, function(images) {
        $.each(images.Images, function() {
            var url = this[size + "URL"];
            console.log("Add img" + url);
            ul.append("<li title=\"" +  url + "\" /></li>");
        });
        //get external javascript script here after images are inserted.
        $.getScript('http://mysite.com/path/to/myscriptfile.js');
    });
});
```

If you need to wait until all the images are actually loaded, you will have to attach a load() event to each image and do a check to see if they are all loaded or something similar..

Comment: my script will get the src and write it in the UL LI tag, then the background should take over and stretch em. It appears though, that the background script is firing before the image src tags are complete

Comment: So I guess that yes the tags would have to be written before the background script could be run

Comment: Would needing the tags to be written constitute needing the images to load?

Comment: That depends on the script you are loading, and it's not possible to say much about it really. If the new script redraws and needs the images to be loaded to do so, or uses the dimensions of the images in some way, they will usually have to be loaded. If the script only needs the elements themselves i.e. only extracts the HTML or something like that, then the fact that they are inserted in the DOM should be enough. If the new script is not dependant on the images at all, there's no need to worry about the images etc. So hard to say for somenone that has not seen the whole thing ?

Answer (score 0):

put your image import code within a

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

and rest of your imports within a

```
$(window).load(function() {

});
```